# Android: Stretching rows in TableLayout programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to create a TableLayout dynamically which has all its rows stretched like shown [in this tutorial](http://radioal.blogspot.com/2011/05/stretching-rows-in-android-tablelayout.html). I've accomplished it via XML, but I'd like to do it from the Activity. Here is the code I've tried so far without success:

```
public View getTableWithAllRowsStretchedView() {
    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

    TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(this);
    tableLayout.setStretchAllColumns(true);
    tableLayout.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    tableLayout.setWeightSum(4);


    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
        tableRow.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tableRow.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1.0f));

        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            Button button = new Button(this);
            final int buttonNumber = (j + i * 4);
            button.setText("" + buttonNumber);
            button.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

            tableRow.addView(button);
        }
        tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
    }

    linearLayout.addView(tableLayout);
    return linearLayout;
}
```

Thank you very much in advance.

***EDIT***

```
Screenshot of what I have
```

[image]

```
what I expect
```

[image]

Comment: can you add current and expected screen-shot?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your rows need the parent's `LayoutParams`:

```
tableRow.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1.0f));
```

Comment: @slukain: your answer is correct, but just a simple question: how to know which Layout class needs to be used? like you've replaced TableRow with TableLayout, why?

Comment: @Waqas You need the parent's `LayoutParams`. The buttons have the `TableRow` params, the row has the `TableLayout` params, and the table should have the `LinearLayout` params(it works with the `TableLayout`, I think, because `TableLayout.LayoutParams` are derived from `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`, also `TableLayout` is an extension of a `LinearLayout`).

Comment: I have one question left: why the hell android doesn't even give any warning or exception when some poor guy like me pushes wrong kind of LayoutParams to a View?

Comment: @SargeBorsch The documentation lacks a bit regarding the `LayoutParams` use, but at least it should be a mistake that you do only once.

Answer (score 0):

**Luksprog**'s answer is correct .

for Stretch in horizontal , do this :

```
TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
            tableRow.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f));
```

for Stretch in vertical , do this :

```
TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
            tableRow.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1.0f));
```

for Stretch in width and height layout , do this :

```
TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
            tableRow.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1.0f));
```