# Android TableLayout match column heights programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm creating a table dynamically from java. My columns are of fixed width and for borders i have used trick of giving margin and setting background color of column views. the problem is that when a TextView goes to multi-line then it changes the height of whole row and in this case the TextViews with single line retain there background to one line and causing blank space.. how can i make column height of all views to same as the max one. Matach_Parent is not working.
for better understanding here below is image of my table and the blank spaces are problem that how can i fill them so that my borders look good and uniform.[image]

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/9683743/538169

Answer (score 0):

Just hard code the max number of lines for each text view. There are methods to do this using Java in the TextView class.

TextView tv = new TextView(context);
tv.setMaxLines(2);

Comment: thanks for answer but i don't want textview to restricted to some specific lines it may goes for three or four lines and want rest of the columns to equalize the max one. i solved the problem by putting attribute match parent in the properties of table row