# Android - UI XML to Java Code - Dynamic - LayoutParams Button with Weight

Tags: xml, layout, dynamic, user-interface

Hi there guys I a trying to manage a UI programmatically, I will add some rows to a Table, but the number of the rows are not always the same.. So I am trying to do this via code, programatically so it can be Dynamic.

I already made an attempt, just need to know how to convert the layoutparams of the ImageButton and Button... Both must be the same way, they are both buttons..

Thanks alot in advance!!

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >



    <TableLayout 
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:stretchColumns="*"
             >


            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/removeIconDesc"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_weight="0.3"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/remove_icon" 
                    android:background="@null"/>



                <Button
                     android:layout_width="0dip"
                     android:layout_weight="1"
                     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                     android:id="@+id/button1"
                     android:text="@string/button1" 
                     android:background="@drawable/pressed"
                     android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow_left"
                     />

                <Button
                     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                     android:layout_width="0dip"
                     android:layout_weight="1"
                     android:id="@+id/button2"
                     android:text="@string/button1" 
                     android:background="@drawable/pressed"
                     android:drawableLeft="@drawable/arrow_right"

                     />

                  <ImageButton
                    android:contentDescription="@string/removeIconDesc"
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_weight="0.3"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/remove_icon" 
                    android:background="@null"/>
            </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

I am trying to convert this UI defined in XML to java code, because I will need to do it dynamically, my best attempt so far was this one below:
But now I cant move on.. because I can't set the weight for the LayoutParams of my ImageButton and Buttons...

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    tLayout = new TableLayout(this);
    tLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    tLayout.setStretchAllColumns(true);

    TableRow tbRow = new TableRow(mainActivity);

    TableRow.LayoutParams tL = new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    tL.weight = 1;

    tbRow.setLayoutParams(tL);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams iM = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);   //this is the right LayoutParams for the ImageButton... I guess
    iM.weight = 0 -- This is not possible.... Error On IDE


    //still need to do the translation to the two buttons... and the other ImageButton, but knowing how to do for the ImageButton I guess I can do the rest..


    setContentView(tLayout);
}
```

Thanks alot in advance community ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, removing the line that stretched the columns of the table layout and removing also the methods where I put the background of imagebutton as null...

Like this:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        tLayout = new TableLayout(this);
        tLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));


        TableRow tbRow = new TableRow(this);

        TableRow.LayoutParams tL = new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        tL.weight = 1;

        TableRow.LayoutParams iM = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);   //this if for the ImageButton..
        iM.weight = (float) 0.3;


        TableRow.LayoutParams iMB = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);   //this if for the ImageButton..
        iMB.weight = (float) 1;


        ImageButton m = new ImageButton(this);
        m.setImageResource(R.drawable.remove_icon);

        m.setLayoutParams(iM);

        Button b = new Button(this);

        b.setText("Cenas");
        b.setLayoutParams(iMB);
        b.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,0,R.drawable.arrow_left,0);

        Button b2 = new Button(this);
        b2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pressed);
        b2.setText("Conas");
        b2.setLayoutParams(iMB);
        b2.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.arrow_right,0,0,0);

        ImageButton m2 = new ImageButton(this);
        m2.setImageResource(R.drawable.remove_icon);
        m2.setLayoutParams(iM);

        tbRow.addView(m);
        tbRow.addView(b);
        tbRow.addView(b2);
        tbRow.addView(m2);

        tLayout.addView(tbRow, tL);


        setContentView(tLayout);




    }
```

Comment: It seems that its not stretching the rows to fill the entire screen... can someone help me?? thanks alot in advance!

Comment: Well I got my problem fixed again :P
Using this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683006/android-stretching-rows-in-tablelayout-programmatically
Sorry guys