# Auto adjust margin between TableRow to fit TableLayout vertically

Tags: android, android-layout, tablelayout

In my application, I'm adding the TableLayout. Then, I'm adding the TableRows dynamically. The number of rows can vary.
What I need is the rows to occupy entire TableLayout vertically. There is one solution here: [Android: Stretching rows in TableLayout programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683006/android-stretching-rows-in-tablelayout-programmatically)

However it increases the height of TableRow children! I want to add extra margin between the rows instead of stretching the height of the views in the table rows.

Is this possible to adjust margin programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can set margin to the table layout.

```
TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);  
TableLayout.LayoutParams tableRowParams=
new TableLayout.LayoutParams
(TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

int leftMargin=10;
int topMargin=2;
int rightMargin=10;
int bottomMargin=2;

tableRowParams.setMargins(leftMargin, topMargin, rightMargin, bottomMargin);

tr.setLayoutParams(tableRowParams);
```

Comment: Yes, we can set the margin, but I want it to be done dynamically to make sure the entire TableLayout is fill irrespective of the number of rows I add to the layout. The margin between the rows should adjusted automatically!