# Three textviews with equal width in the same row (Table-layout)

Tags: layout, textview, tablelayout, android-tablelayout

I have a tablelayout in which each row consists of three textviews.
I don't know the number of rows so I can't set the height of the textviews from the XML layout and I need to do that programmatically.
The next code displays the textviews but not in proper height.. how to do that programmatically in the code?

```
        TableRow row= new TableRow(this);
        TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        row.setLayoutParams(lp);
        row.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        tv1 =new TextView(this);
        tv2 =new TextView(this);
        tv3 =new TextView(this);

        tv1.setText(a);
        tv2.setText(b);
        tv3.setText(c);

        row.addView(tv1,0);
        row.addView(tv2,1);
        row.addView(tv3,2);

        tablelayout.addView(row);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want that  the TableLayout height  matchs to its parent 
see this post:
[Android: Stretching rows in TableLayout programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683006/android-stretching-rows-in-tablelayout-programmatically?noredirect=1&lq=1)

and if you want to have columns with equal width have a look at this:

[Set equal width of columns in table layout in Android [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647177/set-equal-width-of-columns-in-table-layout-in-android)